# How to compare enum in arduino?

Tags: enums, arduino

I am facing an issue with arduino, since I want to change the state of my device using an `enum`, but it doesn't seeem to work, my code looks like below. I am not entirely sure where it goes wrong, I think as well that the comparison between `settingTo` and `toP2P` could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
String toP2P = "503250"
String toABP = "414250";
String settingTo = LoRa_Tx.dataRX.substring(indx);

if( settingTo == toP2P ) {
    //switching to P2P
    Serial.println("current mode 1 "+(String)  LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx);
    if(LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx != LoRa_Tx.LoRaMod){
        LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx = LoRa_Tx.LoRaMod;
    }    
} else if(settingTo == toABP){
    //switching to ABP
    if(LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx != LoRa_Tx.LoRaWan){
        LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx = LoRa_Tx.LoRaWan;}
    }
}
```

My class has the `enum` defined as

```
typedef enum modeRxTx{LoRaMod, LoRaWan, Idle} ;
modeRxTx current_modeRxTx = Idle;
```

Comment: Does your compiler emit any warning?

Comment: Can you print the data contained in `settingTo`?

Comment: @purplepsycho not it doesn't

Comment: @purplepsycho  the content of `settingTo` is 503250

Comment: are you sure there's no hidden character ( `\n`, `\r`, ...)

Comment: how can I be sure? I plot with `Serial.println` should I use write?

Comment: To know that, you can use `Serial.println("--" + settingTo + "--");`

Comment: I have used your print and  I see this Received somenthing `534554544F503250
SETTO command does appears!
--50325--
toP2P>503250
current mode 0 1
current mode 2 1` so the comparison `settingTo == toP2P` seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid the `String` class, as it will eventually cause problems.  However, given that the `LoRa_Tx` appears to have a `String` member, here is one way to watch for those two modes:

```
  if ((indx > -1) && (LoRa_Tx.dataRx.length() >= indx+5)) {
    const char *settingTo = &LoRa_Tx.dataRx.c_str()[ indx ];

    if ( strncmp_P( settingTo, PSTR("503250"), 6 ) == 0 ) {
        //switching to P2P
        Serial.print( F("current mode 1 ") );  //  <-- saves RAM!
        Serial.println( LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx );
        if(LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx != LoRa_Tx.LoRaMod) {
            LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx = LoRa_Tx.LoRaMod;
        }    
    } else if ( strncmp_P( settingTo, PSTR("414250"), 6 ) == 0 ) {
        //switching to ABP
        if(LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx != LoRa_Tx.LoRaWan) {
            LoRa_Tx.current_modeRxTx = LoRa_Tx.LoRaWan;
        }
    }
  }
```

Instead of creating a substring, it just makes a pointer to the actual characters of `data_Rx`.  The `c_str()` function returns a pointer to the first character (zero-based index) or the `String`, and the `[ indx ]` is the first of the mode number characters.  Finally, the `&` is a pointer to the first mode number character.

Next, it uses a standard library function, `strncmp_P` (documented [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#ga3139220accf77b43102c23b58d249ee9)), to compare those mode number characters with the modes you are looking for, and it only compares up to 6 characters.  You don't say if there's a delimiter after "503250", so I don't know if "50325076" is possible and should be rejected.

The `strncmp_P` expects to get a PROGMEM string as the second argument, not just a `const char *`, so that's what the `PSTR` macro does.  This saves RAM because the PSTR will be stored and compared from FLASH memory (aka PROGMEM).  The `Serial.print` statements should use the `F()` macro for the same reason.